# opencart 3 sitemap submitting issue in webmaster tool

Tags: opencart, sitemap, opencart-3

i am facing an issue to submit my site map on google webmaster tool, i have tried with both ways by submitting **sitename.com/sitemap.xml** as well as enabled extension from **extensions->Feeds->Google Sitemap->Enable** and share the Data Feed Url starting form

```
index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap
```

but on **sitename.com/sitemap.xml** webmaster tool showing error

> Sitemap can be read, but has errors General HTTP error 1 instance We
>   encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please
>   ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the
>   location you provided and then resubmit. Examples HTTP Error: 404

and on **Data Feed Url** webmaster tool showing error

> Sitemap could not be read

i am using opencart 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research, i found the solution and that issue is its due to .htaccess file

i just commented `RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]` this line of code in .htaccess file and generated sitemap.xml online and pasted it into root folder of website, and resubmitted the sitemap.